# Confusion in a Simple probability problem

Tags: probability, independence

Suppose if i roll a fair die 6 times, what is the probability of getting (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)?

The answer is $(\frac{1}{6})^6$, and the reasoning is as follows: Assuming independence,
$$P(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)= P(1)\cdots P(1)$$
Since the die is fair, $P(1)=\frac{1}{6}$, and hence the result.

My question is, What does independence mean here?  Is it independent of the event or something else?

In short, I want to know why $P(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)= P(1)\cdots P(1)$?. (I have no problem with assuming independence). Please help.

Answer (score 3):

> "Two events are independent... if the occurrence of one does not affect the probability of occurrence of the other." [Source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Independence_(probability_theory))

The action of rolling any die, in this question, doesn't magically make any other die 'unfair', thus, the event of each die landing on a certain number is independent, and the probability of **all** dice landing on $1$, is equal to the multiplication of probabilities of each die landing on $1$.

Comment: In my question what are the events? Are they event of 1 occurring in i th roll? In that case How we know the probability of that event is (1/6)? All I know is the probability of roll of 1 die. There Is something more I'm missing.

Comment: The independent events are the each of the events that any die will land on $1$, as my answer has suggested.

Comment: A fair die has **$6$** sides, and the number $1$ appears exactly **$1$** time on it. '$1$ out of $6$' can be expressed as a fraction: $\frac 16$.

Comment: Could you please explain what are actually those events you claim to be independent? My sample space is of the form (a,b,c,d,e,f) where a,...,f are numbers between 1 to 6. and event must be a subset of this sample space.

Comment: The event that the **first** die you roll would land on $1$, is independent from the event that the **second** die you roll would land on $1$, and both are independent from the event that the **third** die you roll would land on $1$, and so on, such as that **each such event is independent from all others**, for the reasons I have stated in my answer.

Comment: I guess it makes sense now. Just a final question. I know in tossing one die, the probability of getting  1 is 1/6. with this data, how could I conclude in an experiment of tossing 6 dices the probability of an event that first die land on 1 is 1/6/? (In this particular question what I'm asking may sound stupid, but in a more complicated problem, it may not be this trivial)

Comment: No question is stupid. Since the events are independent, the order of rolling the dice does not matter, and more specifically, the order does not alter the probability of the dice landing on $1$. **This is the essence of independence** - you can think of each die roll as if it is completely not affected by any other events. By the way, if I have been any help, consider accepting my answer, since it is common practice around here.

Comment: @CloudJRK, If I have been any help, consider accepting my answer, since it is common practice around here.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, the answer is definitely not $1/36$, as $P(1,1,1,1,1,1) = P(1) \cdots P(1) = (1/6)^6$. In probability theory, two events $E$ and $F$ are **independent** if $P(E \cap F) = P(E) P(F)$, which in the context of the problem means that $P(1)$ always occurs with probability $1/6$. You used the condition that events are independent in your assertion that $P(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1) = P(1) \cdots P(1)$.

Comment: sorry, it must be $(1/6)^6$. That's a typo

Comment: In my question what are the events? Are they event of 1 occurring in i th roll? In that case How we know the probability of that event is (1/6)?

Comment: Better to say iff (if and only if). The question statement posits independence, and you need to use the implication in that direction to solve.

Comment: Definitions are always if and only if. But usually, authors use only if. and that's fine